# MAUI Shell navigation: how to navigate from a modal page to a non-modal page?

Tags: maui

I have a navigation issue in a MAUI.Net app. To illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, here is a diagram:

[image]

There are three potential routes, A,B and C. The user will select an item on Page 1: this may be an item which requires some form of confirmation from the user before Page 2 can be shown. I would like this to be a modal page that appears if required. If no confirmation is required, page 2 will be loaded. This works fine using the following code:

```
if (confirmation not required)
{
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"Page2", parameter);
}
else
{
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"AGREEMENTPAGE", parameter);
}
```

I have `Shell.PresentationMode="Modal"` set on the Agreement page.

However, this means that when the agreement page navigates to page 2, page 2 now displays as a modal page also, which is not the desired behaviour.

Navigation between Page 1 and Page 2 works fine if the agreement page is not required.

In terms of navigation between Page 1 and Page 2 **when the agreement page is required**, I can make it work IF I display the Agreement page as a normal (non-modal) page, and then remove the most recent history from the navigation stack when Page 2 loads, if it arrived from the agreement page:

`Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToArray().Last());`

However, I lose the modal behaviour in between page 1 and 2.

The final thing I tried was to add a `TaskCompletionSource` to the agreement page, and amend the calling code to something like this (it may be slightly wrong as I abandoned this approach, but hopefully it makes the point):

```
CompliancePage c = new CompliancePage(parameters etc);
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(c);
bool result = await c.ModalDismissedTask;
if (result) {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Page 2", parameter);
}
```

This was the closest I got. However, the modal closed, the new page (page 2) appeared, and then it navigated back to page 1. At this point, I am out of ideas! I feel like there must be something simple I've missed, as I got so close, but ultimately, not quite there.

I have worked around it for now like this:

```
CompliancePage cp = new CompliancePage(fireContext, mapper) { MyJob = job };
await Navigation.PushAsync(cp, true);
bool result = await cp.ModalDismissedTask;
await Task.Delay(600);
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"SurveySelectionPage", parameter);
```

I feel there must be a better way though?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you use the `CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup` instead of the modal page. Such as:

```
<views:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:SkyObservers.Localization"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
         x:Class="NameSpace.AGREEMENTPAGE"
         CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
         Shell.PresentationMode="Modal">
```

And then you will not meet the navigation problem you mentioned. For more information, you can refer to the official document about [Popup in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup).

In addition, you said:

> I have Shell.PresentationMode="Modal" set on the Agreement page.
>
> However, this means that when the agreement page navigates to page 2,
> page 2 now displays as a modal page also, which is not the desired
> behaviour.

Did you try to set the `Shell.PresentationMode="Animated"` (default value) for the Page 2?

Comment: I have looked in to ```CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup``` but I prefer the look and feel from using the native Modal navigation. I hadn't tried setting the ```Shell.PresentationMode="Animated"``` on Page 2, so I tried that, but it doesn't help.

Comment: But according to the official document about [Set page presentation mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-8.0#set-page-presentation-mode), it should work. You can report this on the [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). @ChrisK